# IXAudio2::CreateSourceVoice method Failing

Tags: xaudio2

I am trying to play a basic sound effect using XAudio2 and C++ by following the steps listed here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It seems to me as though XAudio2 is currently initializing properly and the mastering voice is being creating. I am then populating a WAVEFORMATEX structure and a XAUDIO2_BUFFER, structure.

Currently, I am stuck on the CreateSourceVoice() method. It is returning HRESULT 0x88960003, which MSDN says is the XAUDIO2_E_XAPO_CREATION_FAILED result. What I cannot figure out, however, is what is causing it to fail. Is there a way to generate more useful error messages from XAudio2 methods, ones that might be useful in debugging? Is there a common reason why this method fails? I haven't been able to find any detailed information about this issue.

Here is how I initialize XAudio2:

```
    HRESULT hr;

    if (FAILED(hr = XAudio2Create(&xAudio, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR)))
    {

        return hr;

    }

    if (FAILED(hr = xAudio->CreateMasteringVoice(&masteringVoice)))
    {

        return hr;

    }

    return S_OK;
```

Here is how I am Populating my structures:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
    {

        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    }

    if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
    {

        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    }

    DWORD dwChunkSize;
    DWORD dwChunkPosition;

    FindChunk(hFile, fourccRIFF, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

    DWORD fileType;

    ReadChunkData(hFile, &fileType, sizeof(DWORD), dwChunkPosition);

    if (fileType != fourccWAVE)
    {

        return S_FALSE;

    }

    FindChunk(hFile, fourccFMT, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
    ReadChunkData(hFile, wfx, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

    FindChunk(hFile, fourccDATA, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

    BYTE* dataBuffer = new BYTE[dwChunkSize];
    ReadChunkData(hFile, dataBuffer, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

    buffer->AudioBytes = dwChunkSize;
    buffer->pAudioData = dataBuffer;
    buffer->Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;

    return S_OK;
```

I then call CreateSourceVoice(), but sourceVoice is NULL following the call:

```
DXHelpers::XAudioManager::GetManager()->GetXAudio()->CreateSourceVoice(&sourceVoice, (WAVEFORMATEX*)&wfx);
```

Comment: Are you using XAudio 2.7 (DirectX SDK) or XAudio 2.8 (Windows 8.x SDK)? See [XAudio2 and Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8-consumer-preview.aspx)

Comment: Also, you might want to check out [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/12/25/directx-tool-kit-for-audio.aspx). It shows how to enable debugging for both XAudio 2.7 and XAudio 2.8.

Comment: @Chuck Walbourn Thank you so much for that suggestion! I was wasting hours trying to figure out this error and it never occurred to me that I may be mixing my XAudio2 libs and headers with different versions. Now I'm using v2.8 consistently and it's working great! Thanks!